# Using Sitecore Source value to populate droplink field

Tags: sitecore, datatemplate

using Sitecore I have created a data template

### Person Gender

Text : Single Line Text
Key : Number

Then I created 2 new instances of this template in Global content tree:

### Global/Gender

Text = Male
Key =0

Text = Female
Key=1

After all I've created a new Data Template, called: Person

### Person

Name : Single Line
Gender: DropLink (Source: /sitecore/content/home/global/gender/*)

But in instances of Person, DropLink field dosen't show me Female and Male items to select.

Answer (score 2):

Set `Source` of the `Gender` field to the parent path:

```
/sitecore/content/home/global/gender
```

Skip the `/*` at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Set source as shown below:

> datasource=/sitecore/content/home/global/gender

Comment: You can format code blocks using backsticks `code` or ```code```